# I can't assign the specific value from a data.frame to a vector

Tags: r

RStudio ver: Version 1.0.143
Windows ver: Windows 10 Pro
I want to create a loop, which can give the 20th hospital of each state, but the result I received has nothing but numbers. When I tried my code inside the loop with a specific state, I found that the value I want to assign to the vector automatically transferred into numbers. How can I assign the content in the data.frame to the vector?

```
> hos_req <- c()
> Obs_i[20, 2]
[1] D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
98 Levels: ANDALUSIA REGIONAL HOSPITAL ATHENS-LIMESTONE HOSPITAL ATMORE COMMUNITY HOSPITAL ... WIREGRASS MEDICAL CENTER
> hos_req[i] <- Obs_i[20, 2]
> hos_req[i]
GU 
24
```

Comment: you could try `hos_req[i] <- as.character(Obs_i[20, 2])` to remove the factor.

Comment: @desc Thank you very much, it do work.